# Caching data from occasionally disconnected downstream system

Tags: .net, caching, architecture, asp.net-web-api2, offline-caching

Are there any architectural patterns or solutions for caching data in occasionally disconnected downstream systems?

In a situation where a .Net WebAPI 2 REST API to surface resources needs to read from a system which has no guaranteed uptime, what would be a good pattern/solution which could cache data on the server side, if the downstream system was unavailable?

Before re-inventing what must be a ready-existent solution, are there any .Net solutions for this problem?

I was thinking something similar to the following process diagram, however I'm interested to see other solutions.

[image]

---

**Edit:** The upstream systems are REST APIs and an SAP system, which is accessed using the SAP RFC APIs.

Comment: You are going to have troubles here because you aren't really looking for a [cache][1], you are looking for a disconnected replica.  A cache is a performance enhancing solution, in which misses can always occur.  You are looking for a disconnected replica.

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29

Comment: I think you will have more luck in finding out-of-box solutions if you can give more details about the source of the data.  For example, if the third-party-system is a RDMS, there are lots of good solutions.  If the third-party-system is file systems, there are other good solutions.  If the third-party-system is a website, you have different solutions.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am looking for a generic solution which we can use for any upstream data source. I agree this is more of a local replica than a 'cache'. If the data is not available in the 'cache', not returning when the upstream system is down isn't the end of the world, but being able to give some results would be better than none.

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge on an out-of-box SAP disconnected replica system.  Varnish is a pretty good out-of-box rest cache, with the ability to deal with back-end system-down via it's grace-period handling.

This will not act as a full store though, so data that is not "cached" will not be available.  It does seem like a fairly straight-forward implementation though, and will probably improve your performance as well (a nice side-effect).

It isn't exactly what you are looking for though, as you really want something that writes a replica for each request, so you can fall-back to it.

This seems like another pretty good solution, which could work for either the REST or the SAP data:  [Generating Occasionally Disconnected WPF App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257609/generating-occasionally-disconnected-wpf-app)